# Getting my custom font to work in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts

I am attempting to get a custom font working in Rails 4. Here's what I have in my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas';
    src: url('<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.eot' %>');
    src: url('<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix' %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.woff' %>') format('woff'),
         url('<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.ttf' %>') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular' %>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I added the font files into `app/assets/fonts`:

```
bebasneue-webfont-069a8fc829e693fcf470f2352359e221.woff
bebasneue-webfont-56194c50f0b197ee12f067a502a17b30.svg
bebasneue-webfont-755b9b8c0760ef96285f451dca15e4ba.eot
bebasneue-webfont-7d82d863523d9e753d1e51e240a48b6f.ttf
```

in `config/application.rb` I added the following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
```

Then I simply reference it as the following in my CSS markup:

```
.lineup .table .logos .price {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'bebas', sans-serif;
}
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick. Is something obvious missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas';
    src: url("<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.eot' %>");
    src: url("<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix' %>") format('embedded-opentype'),
         url("<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.woff' %>") format('woff'),
         url("<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.ttf' %>") format('truetype'),
         url("<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular' %>") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

In order to get `url(<%= asset_path(...) %>)` to work your file would need to have the extension `.css.erb`

Comment: I am using the .css.erb extension, though.

Comment: Try use `font-url` in your original code instead of `url`

Comment: Actually scrap that, possibly try `src: asset-url` in favour or `url` or try removing the single quote that's around your erb tag: `<%= asset_path 'bebasneue-webfont.eot' %>` (see edit above)

Comment: Damn. Ok well I'm just trouble shooting here. Make sure you restart the server before testing the changes. If you copy pasted my anser above i noticed i had a typeo... Im guessing you're getting a 404 and the assets aren't in /assets/ after launching the server correct? Give this a go `src: url("<%= asset_path('fonts.woff') %>");` the problem may be that you were using single instead of double quotes.

Comment: If you copy-pasted the code, there's a double quote missing on line three that might be the culprit.

Comment: I downvoted because you have to use `.erb` to get this to work, and this will not work in the asset pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best using the [`scss` / `sass` preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) to get this working (as opposed to the Rails ERB preprocessor):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas';
    src: asset_url("bebasneue-webfont.eot");
    src: asset_url("bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefi") format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset_url("bebasneue-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
         asset_url("bebasneue-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
         asset_url("bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This means when you precompile the assets, the correct `urls` will be called (even with [fingerprinted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) files). It should also work in development